# How should I change the inputs of faces.findAt() in Abaqus script?

Tags: python, abaqus

I have an Abaqus script and I want to change the partitions' positions and delete one of them based on the user's input. My problem is that each time that I run the model with a different input value and check the script, the numbers showing the coordinate of the face change in faces.findAt(). I want to know the mechanism of the change, so I can modify it based on my own variable or a proper way to prevent changes.

```
 mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['soil'].RemoveFaces(deleteCells=False, faceList=
 mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['soil'].faces.findAt(((12.666667, 46.666667, 
 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)), ))
```

I mean that "12.667" and "46.667" keep changing in each run.

Comment: Is this coming from the Abaqus replay file? Are you selecting a different face? The numbers are probably changing to indicate the location of the chosen faces to be removed. Those numbers are the coordinates where the closest face is chosen. So in your example it looks for two faces at the two sets of coordinates supplied. If that doesn't help, maybe you can edit your question and tell us what the user input is and how you want to identify faces from that.

Comment: For example, when I removed a face that is a rectangle and coordinations of the vertices were:(12,50) (13,50) (12,48) (13,48) . In the jnl file, it appeared like this:
mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['soil'].RemoveFaces(deleteCells=False, faceList=(
    mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['soil'].faces.findAt((12.666667, 49.333333, 
    0.0), ), ))  Why it uses only one set of coordination. What does it mean? It is just arbitrary?